PYGAME How to move 2 diffrent objects with differents speed
I am making a snake game where there are 2 snakes and there is a fruit that makes the snake that eats it move faster.
This is the link for the repo if the code is needed https://github.com/taki1ds/python_snake_game
I tried to put them in different clocks and make the snake that ate the fruit move to blocks but that led to problems.

If you could provide the relevant code in the question (such as the movement code), then it will make it easier to provide suggestions.
